# How do I ask for more meat or rice?

Tags: mandarin

Friendly auntie at more workplace only knows Mandarin. Was wondering how do I ask for more meat/rice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(你)可以多給(我)點肉嗎 - Can you give me a little more meat? Or, May I have a little more meat?

(你)可以(給我)多盛點飯嗎 - Can you give me some more rice? Or, May I have some more rice?

Note that, in Chinese, "我" is not necessary if you are the person asking the favor. But if the favor is for the other person, a pronoun is required:

(你)可以多給**他**點肉嗎 - Can you give him a little more meat? Or, Can he get a little more meat?

(你)可以給**他**多盛點飯嗎 - Can you give him some more rice? Or, Can he get some more rice?

In all cases, "你" can be omitted.